# WPF - Graphics.CopyFromScreen returns a wrong sized image

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, bitmap, screenshot

Using WPF, I would like to take a screenshot of a area defined by a rectangle with the `(x,y)` representing the topleft corner, and the `width` and `height` of the rectangle.

In this example, the rectangle `source` of the screenshot is defined by the topleft corner with source.x=0 and source.y=0, the source.width=200 and source.height=200.

To make sur that the function do what I want, I display the screenshot on the screen as an image. I display the image of the screenshot beside the rectangle `source` on the position `destination`. In this example, `destination` is defined by destination.x = source.x + source.width (=200), destination.y=0, and destination.width and destination.height = 200.

Here is a minimum working example of the application:

```xml
<Window x:Class="ScreenViewerWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScreenViewerWPF"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        
        WindowState="Maximized"
        Topmost="True"
        AllowsTransparency="True"  WindowStyle="None"
        >
    <Window.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.5" Color="White"/>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid Name="grid">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using Image = System.Windows.Controls.Image;

namespace ScreenViewerWPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var source = new
            {
                top = 0,
                left = 0,
                width = 200,
                height = 200
            };
            var dest = new
            {
                top = 0,
                left = 200,
                width = 200,
                height = 200
            };
            //rectangle to visualize the source
            grid.Children.Add(new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle()
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(source.left, source.top, 0, 0),
                Width = source.width,
                Height = source.height,
                Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0)),
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
            });
            // rectangle to visualize the destination
            grid.Children.Add(new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle()
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(dest.left, dest.top, 0, 0),
                Width = dest.width,
                Height = dest.height,
                Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0, 0, 255)),
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
            });

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(120*source.width/96, 120 * source.height/96);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.CopyFromScreen(source.left, source.top, 0, 0, bmp.Size);
            bmp.Save("test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            // grabed image
            Image image = new()
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(dest.left, dest.top, 0, 0),
                Width = dest.width,
                Height = dest.height,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
            }; grid.Children.Add(image);
            BitmapSource bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                bmp.GetHbitmap(),
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromWidthAndHeight(source.width, source.height)
             );
            image.Source = bitmapSource;
        }
        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
            MakeClicThrough();
        }

        #region make the window clic-through able
        // this is for being able to clic through the form
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
        const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
        const int WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000;
        const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
        private void MakeClicThrough()
        {
            var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
            var style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
            SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, style | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Note this line `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(120*source.width/96, 120 * source.height/96);`, this is the fix I came with to "try" to make the things works. 120 is my computer DPI and 96 is a constante DPI.

Without the `120/96`, I get this (screen shot of the top left of my screen while runing the application):

[image]

As it can be seen, the two images does not match, the right one is like "zoomed".

With the ratio `120/96`, I get this, which is better but not good enough (as you can see, the line 41 is in the image on the rigth image, when on the left it's bellow the rectangle.

[image]

I would like to have 'exactly' the good image in the rectangle (or as close I possible). And If possible a solution that would be elegante.

Comment: In general, DPI things are complicated and it is hard to identify the root cause without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @emoacht I have edited the post, to add a minimal reproducible example and clarify the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to take into account the scaling of Per-Monitor DPI when calculating actual (physical) geometry on a screen.

```
(...)

var dpi = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(grid);
Bitmap bmp = new((int)(source.width * dpi.DpiScaleX), (int)(source.height * dpi.DpiScaleY));

(...)

BitmapSource bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
    bmp.GetHbitmap(),
    IntPtr.Zero,
    Int32Rect.Empty,
    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions() // or BitmapSizeOptions.FromWidthAndHeight(bmp.Width, bmp.Height)
);
image.Source = bitmapSource;
```

Still the location of Image seems odd but it is caused by WindowState and WindowStyle settings and so not the main topic here.